# Listbox selection to hide/unhide correspondent column

Tags: vba, listbox

I have dynamic rows in Column"A" on Sheet1 which are populated on Listbox selection form.

```
111
222
333
444
....
```

Now on my Sheet2 I have these data transposed on Row B2 as:

```
111 | 222 | 333 | 444 | ...
```

I want to for any selection of items in listbox, code hide correspondent Column. If I select 111 and 333 in the Listbox, it hides entire Column "A" and "C".
Hope it make sense. OK button is supposed to run the code.

```
 Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
        Dim sh1 As Worksheet
        Dim sh2 As Worksheet
        Dim i As Integer, hdn2 As String
        Dim hdn3 As Variant, col As Long, header As Range
        Set sh2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

   Set header = sh2.Range("2:2")

       For i = 0 To Me.lstMultiChoice.ListCount - 1
       col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(lstMultiChoice.List(i, 0), header, 0)
       If Me.lstMultiChoice.Selected(i) = True Then
       sh2.Columns(col).Hidden = False
       hdn2 = hdn2 & lstMultiChoice.List(i, 0) & ","
    Else
       sh2.Columns(col).Hidden = True
    End If
  Next
      Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("List Data")
      hdn3 = Split(Left(hnd2, Len(hdn2) - 1), ",")
      sh2.Range(sh2.Cells(4, 4), sh2.Cells(4 + UBound(hdn3), 4)).Value = Application.Transpose(hdn3)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a new answer for you because editing made a monster out of the other one.
Code now includes looking up where the column really is.
You need to add a line to clear the previous entries starting in D4, because if the previous list was longer, some entries will stay there. You also need error trapping in case the col is not found.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
  Dim sh2 As Worksheet
  Dim i As Integer, hdn2 as string
  Dim hdn3 as Variant, col as long, header as Range
  Set sh2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
  Set header = sh2.Range("2:2")

  For i = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ListBox1.List(i, 0), header, 0)
    If Me.ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
      sh2.Columns(col).Hidden = True
      hdn2 = hdn2 & ListBox1.List(i, 0) & ","
    Else
      sh2.Columns(col).Hidden = False
    End If
  Next
  hdn3 = Split(Left(hnd2, Len(hdn2) - 1), ",")
  Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(4, 4), Sheet1.Cells(4 + UBound(hdn3), 4)).Value = Application.Transpose(hdn3)
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow that's now working as a charm :) I edited slightly your answer(see code in my first post): 1st swap hide/unhide which s Ok 2nd I wanted to write selected items in the listbox to be written in different workbook(LIst Data) but getting error.

Comment: Don't use the name LlstData but look up the name that sheet has in your VBA project explorer, like SheetX. Then use `SheetX.Range(SheetX.Cells....`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly this is what you need:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
  Dim sh1 As Worksheet
  Dim i As Integer, hdn as string
  Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
  hdn = "Hidden columns: "

  For i = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If Me.ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
      sh1.Columns(i + 1).Hidden = True
      hdn = hdn & ListBox1.List(i, 0) & ", "
    Else
      sh1.Columns(i + 1).Hidden = False
    End If
  Next
  Sheet1.Cells(4, 4).Value = Left(hdn, Len(hdn) - 2)
End Sub
```

Comment: @Williams: Thanks for the answer. Your code is hiding Columns based on item orders in listbox ,eg. by selecting row "2" it hide column"B", or selecting row "3" and "4, hides column C & D. There is no match data happens between values betwen cells in row "B" and value in listbox. I am not sure it can be happen.

Comment: Also, How can I export(write) selected items in the listbox into Sheet1 to e.g Cell D4? Thanks

Comment: Since you said `on my Sheet2 I have these data transposed ` I thought the sequence of listitems and columns would be the same.

Comment: Thanks itsLex, unfortunately it's still looking at row order regardless of value ( if we call it header). I swap two values as a test but it didn't work. But your export selected list box value is working. How can I change it to populate these values in column, top to bottom and within cells seperately. Again I appreciate your time and help. Cheers

Comment: You should fill your listbox based on the actual columns. That way the order will always be correct. I edited the code to add your requested range of selected columns.